# Having an issue with Authenticaion for MVC3 Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC application that displays just find in our QA environment, but not in our release environment (2 separate machines, but both machines have the same version of Windows, IIS, and of course, the application code)

It seems that in release, it cannot access the JavaSripts in a js folder. What makes it a really odd problem is that if I simply change the "Physical Path Credentials" property in the Advanced Settings to a user, instead of just leaving it as Application user (pass-through authentication), then everything works ok, EVEN if the Specific User that I put is the actual same user as the Application Pool user! However, when I do that, then the razor code

```
@System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

returns the service account, instead of the actual user browsing the site.

In both environments, everything is the same!

The operating system is:
 Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
 Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

The IIS Version is: 7.5.7600.16385)

The Application Pool uses version .net 4.0, integrated pipeline

For the web app, the only authentication enabled is Windows Authentication.

Can some one help?

Comment: Who has permission to view the `js` folder (and/or the files within) on the server (as in filesystem permissions)? My initial gut instinct is that the problem lies there...

Comment: I added the user (the same user that I'm using for the app pool) to each folder manually and gave all permissions. When that didn't work, I added the user to the admin group. That still did not work. The user itself has access, because as mentioned, when I actually use the "Specific User" in the property setting mentioned above, everything works fine. It only breaks when I use pass through authentication. That's why this is confusing. One would think that pass thru auth will use the user assigned to the app pool.

Comment: Don't quote me on this as I'm not certain, but I think pass-through is what it sounds like - under Windows auth, it'll pass through the authenticated user. So if I were a user logged on as 'Mark', that is who would need to be able to access those files. Give that a go with your own user and see if that is true...?